# Creating Dynamic form in android

Tags: php, android, xml, json

Has anyone faced this feature request and were able to resolve it?  We have a webapps that is capable of creating a form as a template.  That template will basically be called and user will need to fill out the form before it got push into the db.  So the form is created directly inside the application and the fields, labels and variables are all defined when the form is created by user using the apps.  Since the form is always going to be changing, I can't hardcode the activity in android and have to create it manually and recompile every time a new form is created.  Is there a way for us to read the label, variables setting that's stored in db either in XML format or called as JSON and build the form dynamically everytime the form is called via android?  Am I making any sense?  Please advise?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Everything you do in XML (view creation, positioning etc) can be done dynamically via code as well.

A simple way would to be to put a single ScrollView with a single LinearLayout inside it. Then in your activities onCreate(), you can read your JSON or XML file just like any other file (you can store this is assets folder or maybe query it from your backend). Then depending on your variables you can initialize and add TextViews and EditText's to the LinearLayout. The ScrollView will expand infinitely to accommodate all your form elements.

Just make sure you don't do any long-running operation such as querying from your backend or reading from your file in the main UI thread. Another caveat is that if ScrollView does not recycle views and putting too many views in it (say more than 20) can make your application run out of memory and slow down/crash.

Comment: Thanks @Anup Cowkur.  What you described is correct and it can be done that way on the activity side.  But what about the *.java side?  Didn't the java got compiled everytime the apk got generated?  I can always create the java dynamically also but can the android read that file when the application is running?  Wouldn't that potentially becoming a security hole for the apps and the device?  Just wondering..

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by the "*.java side". Whatever code you write in your activity gets compiled into the APK which is loaded onto the device.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a form in relative layout having all the fields/view you require in XML, then on Runtime in code According to your label name in db or whatever you are using, you can hide/show the fields/view which are needed dynamically. This way you can preserve the position and setting of each field as when 1 view is hidden other views are going to take its position.

Comment: Thanks but that's not possible since the possibility of different template got created many times over by different clients and having to recompile the aps everytime there's a template change.